# Ionic 2 - Focus textarea after submit to prevent virtual keyboard from disappearing

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a part of my app that's a chat application where any time I hit the "submit" button, the textarea loses input and the virtual keyboard closes. I tried remedying this by re-focusing the textarea as soon as the form is submitted. The problem is that this works fine when I work with Ionic in the browser, but as soon as I test it on my iOS device, it refuses to refocus on the textarea. Here is the code in my HTML Template:

```
<div class="create-message-block">
    <form [formGroup]="addMessageForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="addMessage(addMessageForm.value, focusableTextarea)">
      <textarea #focusableTextarea [formControl]="addMessageForm.get('message')" placeholder="Write your message..."></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
  </div>

// And here is the add message functionality in my component
addMessage(data, focusableTextarea) {
 // ... a lot of code edited out for sample purposes

  focusableTextarea.focus()
}
```

Does anyone know if there's anything else I can? I've even tried adding a slight timeout where the `.focus()` waits 50ms before it fires. That didn't do anything either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612653/set-focus-on-an-input-with-ionic-2).

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my chat app is use the mousedown event.

```
(mousedown)="preventFocusChange($event)"
```

And in the function

```
preventFocusChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Might not be ideal, but works as promised. Thanks man.